# redirect 404 page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect some page on 404 page. How may I achieve it using htaccess file.

```
http://wowriters.com/author/admin/feed/
http://wowriters.com/reflective-portfolio/essay-writing-service
http://wowriters.com/reflective-portfolio/dissertation-service
http://wowriters.com/samples/essay-writing-service
http://wowriters.com/samples/uae
http://wowriters.com/worlds-biggest-beverages/coursework-help-service
http://wowriters.com/worlds-biggest-beverages/buy-essays
```

Above links should be gone on 404 page.

Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add ErrorDocument 404 before the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your topmost rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /author/admin/feed/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /reflective-portfolio/(essay-writing|dissertation)-service [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /samples/(uae|essay-writing-service) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} worlds-biggest-beverages/(buy-essays|coursework-help-service) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Hello friend,
Above logic not working. My pages are still opening.

Comment: This is my htaccess file code.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /author/admin/feed/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /reflective-portfolio/(essay-writing|dissertation)-service [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /samples/(uae|essay-writing-service) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} worlds-biggest-beverages/(buy-essays|coursework-help-service) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

Comment: paste your entire contents of your .htaccess file. there could be other rules on there that can stop the provided answer.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. My rules are commented.
I am testing this one: http://wowriters.com/reflective-portfolio/dissertation-service

Comment: Now it showing blank 404 page, but my actual 404 page is like this: http://wowriters.com/zee

Will I have to define error 404 template?
If yes then how can I do that?

Comment: Dear sir, My error page is this: error_404.php and it is located in Codeigniter/application/views/html/error_404.php.

Now, Kindly tell me how can I define it in htaccess file?

Comment: I have define custom error page with the name: error_404.php.
http://wowriters.com/zee it means that this page is not find that's why 404 page showoing. I just wanted to show you that my 404 page is like this.

Comment: you may check my updated htaccess file: http://wowriters.com/htaccess.txt
Is it right?

Comment: Yes your .htaccess is correct and I have verified that `http://wowriters.com/reflective-portfolio/dissertation-service` is returning `404` status. However I don't know CI framework to help you further on a custom 404 page. But I think I have solved your problem of returning 404 for these URLs. For CI related problem you may ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://wowriters.com/author/admin/feed/
ErrorDocument 404 http://wowriters.com/reflective-portfolio/essay-writing-service
ErrorDocument 404 http://wowriters.com/reflective-portfolio/dissertation-service
ErrorDocument 404 http://wowriters.com/samples/essay-writing-service
ErrorDocument 404 http://wowriters.com/samples/uae
ErrorDocument 404 http://wowriters.com/worlds-biggest-beverages/coursework-help-service
ErrorDocument 404 http://wowriters.com/worlds-biggest-beverages/buy-essays
```

All the page not found pages will display the links.

Comment: I think you misunderstood use of `ErrorDocument`. Only last `ErrorDocument 404` will be in effect and it just means all 404 URLs on website will be redirected to `http://wowriters.com/worlds-biggest-beverages/buy-essays`

Comment: There is not any error document define in navigation.